# Как можно реализовать отображение кол-во времени / дней после публикации поста?

Tags: html, django, веб-программирование, frontend, jinja

Есть такой код:

```
{% block content %}
<div class="block-news smooth-onset-1s">
    <div class="list-news">
        {% if post %}
            {% for news in post %}
                <div class="content-news">
                    <p class="news-info">
                        <span class="news-creator">{{ news.creator }}</span>
                        <span class="news-time">
                            {{ news.time }}
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <h2><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=news.id %}" class="title-link">{{ news.title }}</a></h2>
                    <p>{{ news.content|linebreaks }}</p>

                    {% if news.image %}
                        <img src="{{ news.image.url }}">

                    {% else %}
                    {% endif %}
                    <br>
                    <a href="" class="scrollTop">Наверх</a>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Как можно сделать так, чтобы вместо строки с `news.time` было кол-во дней с момента публикации? По типу: 7 дней назад, 2 часа назад, 14:56 (если дата публикации совпадает с сегодняшней датой)

Заранее спасибо, готов дополнить вопрос

Доп.

```
# models.py

from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def default_start_time():
    now = datetime.now()
    start = now.replace(hour=22, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    return start if start > now else start + timedelta(days=1)

class Post(models.Model):
    creator = models.CharField('Автор', max_length=50)
    title = models.CharField('Заголовок', max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField('Содержимое')
    date = models.DateField(_('Дата'), default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    time = models.TimeField('Время', default=default_start_time)

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Новости'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Новости'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не надо помещать никакую логику в тимплейты, это другой слой, который должен отвечать только за отрисовку данных. Самый правильный способ, как по мне, сделать аннотацию внутри кверисета, которая будет считать timedelta  между текущей датой и post.time. И в тимплейте обращаться к этому аннотированному полю.

Comment: Привет! В Django я недавно, можете пожалуйста прикрепить ссылку на документацию) Спасибо!

Comment: Вот пример ответа на ваш вопрос - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47222061/7024122. После этого в вашем кверисете появится новое поле days (или как вы его сами назовете) к которому вы сможете напрямую обращаться в темплейте.